# Why is my macro specific to just the one excel file?

Tags: excel

How do I save a macro so that I can use the same macro in any excel file that I create? For now it is available only in the original excel file where I created the macro.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

Comment: Also this guide may be of help: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm